# how to make TextView selectable under api 11

Tags: android, textview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I need to have a text that will be shown to the user, and it will be possible to select a part of it and copy it to the clipboard.
But without the keyboard open.
I know that on api 11 and newer i can just use

```
text.setTextIsSelectable (true);
```

But what is the solution to lower OS versions?

Comment: you mean testview clickable?

Comment: no. i mean that the user can choose part of the text that was shown in  TextView and can copy it to paste it to the clipboard.

Comment: `setTextIsSelectable()` works fine for HoneyComb+

Comment: and what about under api 11.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625300/selecting-text-on-textview-android-2-2

Comment: I solved this problem : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042308/new-selectable-textview-in-android-3-api-level-11-component

Comment: Why not just use and edittext that doesn't allow editing? And theme it like a textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ContextMenu` and `CLIPBOARD_SERVICE`:

```
private TextView mTextView;

protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
registerForContextMenu(mTextView);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        menu.setHeaderTitle(textView.getText()).add(0, 0, 0, R.string.menu_copy_to_clipboard);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ((ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)).setText(mTextView.getText());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to allow the user to select part of the text? and not all of the text, as you suggested in your solution. So I allow him to experience normal use of copy text.

Answer (score 0):

After a long and time consuming search, I can't find a component that can select text in textview for android API level <=11. I have written this component that may be of help to you :
[new Selectable TextView in android 3 (API <=11) component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042308/new-selectable-textview-in-android-3-api-11-component)