# How to support textView.setTextIsSelectable in lower android versions?

Tags: android, textview, android-support-library

```
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

requires min API level 11.

Is there anyway to support it from API level 8+ ?

Comment: android:textIsSelectable in xml

Comment: i want in code, 
i'm dynamically changing it to "true" and false

Comment: Do you had a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167330/how-to-make-textview-selectable-under-api-11 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625300/selecting-text-on-textview-android-2-2 ?

Answer (score 2):

There are some methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167330/how-to-make-textview-selectable-under-api-11) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042308/new-selectable-textview-in-android-3-api-11-component), but there's probably no way to do this to achieve same functionality

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class by extending TextView class and override setTextIsSelectable

```
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void setTextIsSelectable(boolean selectable) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        super.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    else
    {   
        super.setLongClickable(true);
        super.setOnLongClickListener(getSelectableLongClick());
        super.setOnTouchListener(getSelectableOnTouch());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using EditText.
Where is getSelectableLongClick() and getSelectableOnTouch()  ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using EditText with the attributes:

```
android:inputType="none"
android:background="@null"
```

And do this in code:

```
editText.setKeyListener(null);
```

Which makes EditText non-editable but still with select and copy functionality. The only drawback is the visible cursor when the widget is focused. I can't set `android:cursorVisible` to `false` because it hides the selection background together with the cursor.